# MySQL Views: Sub-Joins

Tags: sql, mysql, view

I am wanting to have a view table that aggregates rows from four tables.

The first primary table is **client** and is just a primary key unique id and a profile_id. The second table, **profile**, holds all of the firstname, address, zipcode kind of information. The third table is **email**; there can be many email objects to one client object but there is only one email object with the *primary* column flagged true; the fourth table is **phone** - this is also a many to one relationship (there can be cellphones, homephones, fax numbers, etc...) and only one object can have the *primary* column flagged.

JOINing the **client** table with the **profile** table is easy as it's one to one; what I want advice on is how to go about selecting an email and phone object based on the *primary* column (rather than the first JOINed result).

Any resources I can be pointed to would be greatly appreciated; as I have been searching for material for a few days.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select whatevercolumnsyouwant
  from client
  join profile using (profile_id)
  join email on client.profile_id = email.profile_id
            and email.primary = 1
  join phone on client.profile_id = phone.profile_id
            and phone.primary = 1
where client.id = :whateverclientid
```

the key point is that ON subclauses of JOIN clauses can specify several conditions (in AND, OR, whatever) just like WHERE clauses can but with a more "specific" purpose!

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't really be any problems to joining `email` and `phone` too. Just join them in another straight forward join and add `WHERE phone.primary = TRUE` as an ordinary `WHERE`-claus.

The following, I think, should do it:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM client
  JOIN profile
  ON profile.client_id = client.id
  JOIN email
  ON email.client_id = client.id
  JOIN phone
  ON phone.client_id = client.id
WHERE phone.primary = TRUE AND
      email.primary = TRUE
```